# Is it possible to add a file to the argument list with in netrw?

Tags: netrw, argument-list

I am a heavy user of the argument list and I always have the files which are important for my current task in it.

Now I started to use netrw more often to search through the files system.
But I can't find a way to add the files and to add it to the argument list.

So is it possible to `:arge` a file from within netrw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
c                       make the current netrw directory the current vim directory
:arge <C-r><C-f><CR>    edit the file under the cursor
```

Adding this line to your `vimrc` should allow you to avoid the `c` step:

```
let g:netrw_keepdir = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try netrw v155c -- it provides two maps for argument list handling.  Essentially, ma moves marked file names to the argument list and mA will go the other direction.  You can get v155c from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW